# Swift, how can I get response headers from RestKit?

Tags: swift3, restkit

I have a RestKit request as below. How can I get the auth token from the response headers?

```
    RKObjectManager.shared()
        .getObjectsAtPath(urlString,
                      parameters: paramsDictionary,
             success: {(operation: RKObjectRequestOperation?, result: RKMappingResult?) -> Void in



pod 'RestKit', '~> 0.27.0'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get response header from `RKObjectRequestOperation` like this way.

```
if let operation = operation, let headers = operation.httpRequestOperation.response.allHeaderFields as? [String:Any] {
    print(headers)// Now use subscript with headers dictionary to get your token value
}
```

Comment: I get `Value of type RKObjectRequestOperation has no member response`

Comment: It liked `operation.httpRequestOperation`

Comment: @markhorrocks Actually I have added code from my Objective C, Edited answer :)